# How do I invert the /testfor command's result? (1.12 and below)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

`/testfor`, `/testforblock`, and `/testforblocks` are all part of the same group of commands and are similar in what they do after their test. They are only useful when their output is measured using redstone comparators (not recommended) or when combined in a chain with other commands (most often way)
It's quite simple. If the test returns TRUE, any conditional command blocks later in the chain will run (unless stopped by a different failed command in between). If the test returns FALSE, the conditional command blocks *won't* run.

I would like to invert the check, so that if the entity does **not** exist <sup>`/testfor`</sup>, or if the block is **not** what is specified <sup>`/testforblock`</sup>, or if the block regions **don't** match<sup>`/testforblocks`</sup>, then the subsequent commands in the chain **will** run, and if the check passes, they **will not** run. How can I do this?

(I suspect that for `/testforblock`, it's as simple as placing a `!` before the block name, but I'm not sure if the `!` operator existed in 1.12. For `/testfor` and `/testforblocks`, absolutely no idea.)

Please also consider viewing my other, identical [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/372399/250180) for Minecraft Bedrock Edition.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didn't need `testfor` in 1.12 either. But it's so long ago that I don't fully remember all alternatives anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is to use a second (chain, unconditional) command block checking with the command `/testforblock <coordinates of first command block> command_block * {SuccessCount:0}`, which makes it succeed if the first command block fails (because it's `SuccessCount` is 0), and fail if the first command block suceeded, allowing you to properly condition things off of the inverse.

If the first command block (that you want to fail) is a repeating or chain command block, then you have to use `repeating_command_block` or `chain_command_block` (respectively) instead of just `command_block`, but the command otherwise works the same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding you. The second command block runs regardless of whether the first one suceeds or fails, because it's not conditional. The third command block shouldn't interact with the first one at all.

Comment: Everything that checks if the first command fails should be a conditional chain command block configured to run only if the second command block (with `SuccessCount:0`) succeeds (and thus not even touching the command block containing the original `testfor`)

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, then yes. Feel free to edit this answer to clarify whatever you thought was unclear about it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto @pppery's answer, you should place the second and third commands in a different chain. If you place them in one chain, this will happen when the `/say` was supposed to run:

```
REPEAT, UNCONDITIONAL: /testfor @e[type=MyEntity] || FAILS: The entity was not found.
CHAIN, UNCONDITIONAL: /testforblock x y z command_block * {SuccessCount:0} || PASSES: The first command block did not pass.
CHAIN, CONDITIONAL: /say The first command block failed. || Does not run. The first command failed, and for this to run, both previous ones had to pass, which is impossible since at least one command is bound to fail.
```

If you change it into two chains, this happens:

```
REPEAT, UNCONDITIONAL: /testfor @e[type=MyEntity]
```

```
REPEAT, UNCONDITIONAL: /testforblock x y z command_block * {SuccessCount:0} || PASSES: The first command block did not pass.
CHAIN, CONDITIONAL: /say The first command block failed. || RUNS: All previous commands passed.
```